# Visual Studio not remembering Break point changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Suddenly when I am debugging, say I remove a break point I no longer need then hit play or restart my program, and suddenly the same break point is back.
I clear it again save, and it is back again.

In some cases I remove a break point in others I add a break point.
It seems at random it either brings back or removes the break point or moves the existing break point a line or 2 to the wrong spot.

I have tried restarting VS a few times which works at first but for only a short time.

I have never seen this before and it scares me VS could be behaving so badly.

Is there any easy solution such as clean break points (I would rather not remove all of them)?

Comment: Try removing the break point while you are not debugging. I had this problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, the only way that I get rid of it is putting a break point somewhere and then choose `Clear all breakpoints` from the `Debug` menu.

Comment: I tried stopping the program are removing, but as soon as I start the break point is back. If I restart, I can remove them, but not for long.

Comment: It also seems most if not all of my break points have moved up one line, I fix one and find more with the same issue.

Comment: @Michael Elkin, have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Silverming was right, removing all breakpoints was the way to fix the behavior, but it still looses all break points.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution? (Build | Clean). Also, see if closing VS and deleting *all* the suo files and the obj folder in your solution directory help. It could be that the refactoring support that VS does in the background got messed up. Of course, backup your currently set break points if there are a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the behavior you describe is a sign that the .suo-file (solution-wide user options - located in the solution folder) is corrupt. To test this, you can rename or move the file to an other folder. After that, all your breakpoints and many other settings (e.g. which code-files were opened) will be gone, but the breakpoints should behave as usual again.

**Edit:**

If you don't want to lose your breakpoints, you can export and import them from the breakpoints-window. I think this is a new feature of VS2012 (I tried it in the Premium Edition).

An other possibility is that you are encountering a "feature" that is described here:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/391642/permanently-remove-a-breakpoint-in-visual-studio-during-debugging

Comment: I have a few suo files with name and another with name.v11.suo and what looks like oldname.suo. Renaming just the suo file did not help. The break points became invisible outside debugging and always came back when debugging. Deleting all break points seems to have fixed everything though. Now to re-enter all of them again.

Comment: As far as I know VS2010 and earlier produce a `solutionname.suo` and VS2012 produces `solutionname.v11.suo` and does not use the one without `.v11` at all.

Comment: One more thing: have you searched the VSGallery or the internet for an extension that is able to import and export breakpoints - might be handy if the problem re-appears.

Comment: the .v11.suo does clear all the break points. The new file is about 20 kb compared to 3+ MB, but after clearing break points the file old file shrunk to around 100 kb. Would I be better off using the new file or the old cleaned file?

Comment: Well, .suo files are MS OLE Structured Storage based files that contain multiple binary streams. You can use a [viewer](http://www.mitec.cz/ssv.html) to inspect them. I always have a bad feeling when these files cause VS to behave weirdly, so I prefer to to delete them. But if you have put a lot of effort in the other settings that are stored in the .suo you might want to hope for the best and keep the cleaned file...