# Visual Studio 2012 breakpoints never get permanently cleared

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

It seems as though my breakpoints in Visual Studio 2012 have been persisting forever.  No matter if I clear them during debugging, the red dots seem to re-appear the next time I attach to my IIS process.  How can I permanently clear them?  How do they get permanently set like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio refuses to forget breakpoints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983918/visual-studio-refuses-to-forget-breakpoints)

Comment: It's also possible the .suo file for your project can't be written to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio not remembering Break point changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685455/visual-studio-not-remembering-break-point-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983918/visual-studio-refuses-to-forget-breakpoints), go to Debug menu then Delete All Breakpoints Ctrl+Shift+F9 to get rid of all break points.

Or If you want to get rid of any particular break point, remove it before you start debugging (not during debugging)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in debug when you delete all break points, they won't really be deleted. After you get out of debug, and the project is not running, try to 'Delete all breakpoints' again, and it should clear them.